# Installing another version of linux on my system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, drivers

I need to build locally a driver for "precise" Ubuntu edition (**uname -r** for that system returns **3.2.0-33-generic-pae**).

My local host is **Ubuntu 13.10 'sausy'**.

But I fail to install the linux headers( what should I do to set up the environment I need?)

I downloaded the image from here: [from packages.ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic-pae) but what my next steps should be?

Actually I don't need exact steps but pointing the right direction would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your best bets are probably either a chroot or a full VM.

Comment: Yeah, but i need to be able to perform all the actions manually, w/o VMs..

Comment: What does "doing things manually" have to do with using VMs?

Comment: i mean that i want to avoid using the VMs at all in this case. My host  needs to be configured to perform similar tasks. i have such requirements(

Comment: This requisite doesn't make much sense, but whatever, you can still use a chroot (although you won't be able to actually load the driver after building it).

Comment: That is fine :) the testing env. is on another machine. Mine is only for dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just build the driver (with out installing/testing)

> **then you will just have to download the kernel source of the preferred version (in this case it is 3.2.0-33) from kernel.org, build it with config from your host PC, and then compile your driver/module against that.**

If you plan to install/test then after building the kernel source of the preferred version,

> **install the same to your host PC, then you will be able to insmod the driver you built**

Comment: Thank you, but what about those "linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic-pae" package from "packages.ubuntu.com"? is this package not valid or not suitable?

Comment: those are the package that include the kernel-headers, required to compile kernel modules/drivers

Comment: so, can i use it to build the driver? excuses to such questions - i'm a noob in these kernel-related areas...(

Comment: only the headers are not enough, it is necessary along with other files like system.map, vmlinux and few others. Based on which the drivers would be built